# Constrained Linear Regression with multiple factors in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, categorical-data, factor-analysis, cross-section

I am trying to figure out how to run a simple linear model with two factor variables as regressors without the intercept. In particular, I would need to write a code to replicate the Barra Fundamental Factor Model. It runs T periods cross-sectional regression, regressing N stock returns vs Industry dummy variables and Country dummy variables. In addition, it imposes the following linear constraint: the sum of the coefficients estimated for the country dummy is constrained to 0.

In a simple way, I have the following code:

```
Country <- factor(c('Italy','Spain','Germany'))
Sector  <- factor(c('Financial','Gov','Industrial'))
model   <- lm(y~ Country + Sector + 0)
```

where y is a vector of stock returns.

I need to:

- explicitly extract all the coefficient (that's why I put +0  in the model).
- the sum of the Country coefficients sums up to 0

I tried to use the contrast feature but I didn't understand its functioning.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to run a linear model without an intercept. `coef(model)` will return all your coefficients, which you can then add up.

Comment: This is more a stats question, how to represents contrasts, so I think it on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pcls()` function in the [`mgcv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mgcv). `pcls` stands for *partially constrained least squares*. Specify your equality constraints via the `C` matrix. You will need to supply a valid initial parameter vector, i.e., one that satisfies your equality constraints.